# What can be an efficient data structure for this?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, set

The problem link is: http://www.spoj.com/problems/ORDERSET/en/

In this problem, you have to maintain a dynamic set of numbers which support the two fundamental operations

INSERT(S,x): if x is not in S, insert x into S
DELETE(S,x): if x is in S, delete x from S
and the two type of queries

K-TH(S) : return the k-th smallest element of S
COUNT(S,x): return the number of elements of S smaller than x
Input

Line 1: Q (1 ≤ Q ≤ 200000), the number of operations
In the next Q lines, the first token of each line is a character I, D, K or C meaning that the corresponding operation is INSERT, DELETE, K-TH or COUNT, respectively, following by a whitespace and an integer which is the parameter for that operation.
If the parameter is a value x, it is guaranteed that 0 ≤ |x| ≤ 109. If the parameter is an index k, it is guaranteed that 1 ≤ k ≤ 109.

Output

For each query, print the corresponding result in a single line. In particular, for the queries K-TH, if k is larger than the number of elements in S, print the word 'invalid'.

I thought of using a set here, since the insertion and deletion in a set can be done in logarithmic time. However, I am not sure if set is the ideal data structure for finding the `k'th` element and number of elements less than it. What other DS can I use to make it optimal. Thanks!

Comment: The title (`this`) doesn't pinpoint what your question is about ([ask]). The formatting of your question is dismal for lack of two trailing spaces where you want a new line - but consider using an itemised list.

Answer (score 0):

A [set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_(abstract_data_type)) is an abstract data type, not a data structure. An hash table is a data structure that can be used to implements a set, as is a binary tree.

Speaking of binary tree, it seems well suited for your needs here.

If balanced : fast INSERT and DELETE

If you keep track of subnodes count : K-TH and COUNT should be very fast too